# Why use the Constants interface for SQLite to hold field names?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, constants

In the SQLite chapter of "Hello, Android", an interface `Constants` is created to hold some constant strings: the table name and field names.

Why? How is it more useful to use `TITLE` than `"title"` directly? Is there something else I'm missing?

And by the way: how should it be organized if I need two tables? Should I make `FirstTableConstants` and `SecondTableConstants` interfaces?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html. check the link and the topic under use static final for constants

Comment: because the code results more readable an the probability to address a not existing column (misspelling the column name) decrease near 0

Comment: Go through this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-09-1999/jw-09-cooltools.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use a string more than once, its best to create a constant for it. 
It prevents creation of the string more than once.
Object allocation isn't free so you will see some performance gain.

Consider the case where you create the string in a loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
    System.out.println("title");
}
```

vs using a constant:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
    System.out.println(TITLE);
}
```

If it took 1ms to allocate the string "title", your run time for the first loop code is N X 1ms.

Also building SQL statements with constants will be quicker than repeatedly creating new strings for the statement keywords for types (text, integer,) modifiers (unique, not null), etc.

```
 String TABLE_SCHEMA = "(" +
            ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            COL_FOO1 + " text, " +
            COL_FOO2 + " text, " +
            COL_FOO3 + " text, " + ...
```

If you make " text, " a constant you aren't creating that string over and over again, so your TABLE_SCHEMA string is created quicker.

```
 String TABLE_SCHEMA = "(" +
            ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            COL_FOO1 + TYPE_TEXT +
            COL_FOO2 + TYPE_TEXT +
            COL_FOO3 + TYPE_TEXT + ...
```

Comment: Another advantage is that using constants avoid typos (yep typos may happen ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a class, you should probably have them as public static final String TITLE = "Some Title" field. It's better to use it this way so that you won't make an error while typing it into a command. You'll only have to type the variable name.